# Rails, update the product right after create one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the web app on RoR, but the issue is once the user upload the image, the `product_id` is not associated with the `product_attachments`. Not until I proceed to next form.

Following were my controller
ProductAttachmentsController:

```
class ProductAttachmentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_product_attachment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
    @product_attachments = ProductAttachment.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @product_attachment = ProductAttachment.new
  end

  def create
    @product_attachment = ProductAttachment.new(product_attachment_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product_attachment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product_attachment, notice: 'Product attachment was successfully created.' }
        format.json {render :json => @product_attachment}
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product_attachment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product_attachment.update(product_attachment_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product_attachment.product, notice: 'Product attachment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product_attachment }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product_attachment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @product_attachment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to product_attachments_url, notice: 'Product attachment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_product_attachment
      @product_attachment = ProductAttachment.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def product_attachment_params
      params.require(:product_attachment).permit(:product_id, :attachment)
    end
end
```

How can I trick the `create` method, so it will create a `product_id` when I create `product_attachment`? Currently I need to proceed next step and it trigger `update` method to insert `product_id` in `product_attachments` table. Thanks!!

Comment: Is `product_id` a foreign key or just some string/integer that user can enter?

Comment: @Vasfed `product_id` is not foreign key

Comment: Then how do you "create" it?

Comment: I think it would be better if you give associations between products and product_attachments (has_many, belongs_to). This will make it easier to create attachments as it will automatically set the product_id of the attachment you added to that product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the product attachment id in a session variable

```
  if @product_attachment.save
    session[:product_attachment] = @product_attachment.id ### HERE!
    format.html { redirect_to @product_attachment, notice: 'Product attachment was successfully created.' }
    format.json {render :json => @product_attachment}
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @product_attachment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
```

When you create the product (in the ProductsController ) recall the attachment and update the product_id

```
if @product.save
  if session[:product_attachment]
    ProductAttachment.find(session[:product_attachment]).update_attribute(:product_id, @product.id)
    session[:product_attachment] = nil
  end
  ...
end
```